# Use `ffprobe` to display subtitle content like the `cat` command

Tags: terminal, subtitle, ffprobe

How to use `ffprobe` to select a subtitle from an `mkv` file and display its content?

I expect to have the subtitle content printed on the terminal like the command `cat` would do to a subtitle file.

I know its possible to export the subtitle file and then `cat` it, but is there a direct use for probe?

Comment: How do you want the subtitles displayed? Is srt format OK, for example?

Comment: yes `srt` is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can do that with `ffprobe`, but `ffmpeg` can do that, and output the subtitles to stdout.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -f srt -
```

You can switch out `srt` for any other subtitle format `ffmpeg` understands, such as `ass`.